# How do I optimize a Postgres full text search by multiple words?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a "title" text column and a "ts" textsearch column which I have been using successfully for full text searches.

I want to have a materialized view that I refresh daily with "related" items. It will take the title, split it up into words and perform a search for each word so that it finds related records (I can't search using just the title as that is too specific of search).

This works with a small number of records but when you do it over 1000 times for titles that have multiple words it takes over 1.5 minutes to complete.

How do I optimize my view?

My SQL so far:

```sql
SELECT
    asset.id,
    (
        SELECT
            jsonb_agg(resultsForWord)
        FROM
            UNNEST(
                string_to_array(TRIM(regexp_replace(asset.title, '[^a-zA-Z ]', '', 'g')), ' ')
            ) as word
            INNER JOIN LATERAL 
            (
                SELECT
                    searchresult.id,
                    searchresult.title
                FROM
                    assets searchresult
                WHERE
                    searchresult.id != asset.id AND
                    ts_rank(ts, to_tsquery ('english', word)) > 0.5
                LIMIT 5
            ) AS resultsForWord ON 1=1
     ) results
FROM
    assets asset
GROUP BY asset.id, asset.title;
```

Data is like

| id | title | ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | Hello world! | (generated) |
| b | Another record | (generated) |

"Hello world!" gets split up into "hello" and "world" then it performs a search for "hello" then another search for "world".

Comment: Does every `searchresult` have multiple titles? Otherwise I don't quite get that `GROUP BY searchresult.id`

Comment: @Bergi A `searchresult` will have a title with multiple words in them. I dont care about their contents - I have already generated a `ts` column that I am using for the search.

Comment: @Bergi If I don't have it I get ` ERROR: column "searchresult.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: No I mean why are you using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`?

Comment: @Bergi Oh yeah. That was leftover from some copied code. Changed to `WHERE` and removed `GROUP BY`

Comment: That cannot be sped up with an index. You'd need to add an additional `WHERE` condition using `@@`.

Comment: Using ts_rank on something which has not already survived @@ is an invalid use. It won't crash, but what it returns might not be meaningful, and of course it will also be slow.

Comment: There are 1440 minutes in a day.  Why do you care if 1.5 of them are spent doing this?

Comment: @jjanes My mistake - it now takes over 10 minutes on my production database. I asked how to do something else to the query at db admins and now it takes drastically less (https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/313556/254369)